# Subdivision Loop cut doesn't hold

Tags: subdivision-surface

I don't get it why the loop cut doesn't hold on a subdivion surface applied to an object. Is it something wrong with my Loop Cut settings or is there something else I'm not aware of? Only two weeks old in Blender.

[Video with a simple object to understand the issue](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14BLuk9Aq15TSL7-Hu1OGPPRtLO8YzPle/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: You are adding the loop cut and then sliding it by dragging your mouse. The vertices are added as the stats in the lower right corner show. They are just overlapping with other vertices because you dragged them until they where positioned at the next edge loop.

Comment: [Please provide some context and explanation, don't just post a video](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-is-the-problem-with-posting-an-image-or-link-and-asking-how-do-i-do-this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, well first, you might be doing it wrong...

When you make a loop cut, click to establish the loop cut. Once the loop cut has been made, drag it (not holding down the mouse) to the desired location and click again to set it.

Does that work?

Also, just so you know, you don’t ever want to have vertices overlapping—which leads me to:

Pro-tip: if you’re using subsurf and want sharp edges, hit N, which opens up a side bar on the right. In it, in the default Item tab, you’ll see Mean Crease. Select the edges you want to keep sharp, and set their Mean Crease value to 1.00 (or any value in between) to accomplish your creases with no extra vertex data and no overlapping vertices (which will come back to bite you).

Good luck, and happy Blendering,

John